# Maven project build fails in IntelliJ when annotation processors are used (google/auto-value)

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, annotation-processing, auto-value

I use [google/auto-value](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) to create immutable value classes in a maven project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    [...]
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <auto-value.version>1.7</auto-value.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
                            <artifactId>auto-value</artifactId>
                            <version>${auto-value.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-value-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${auto-value.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        [...]

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This works like a charm using the CLI (e.g. `mvn clean test`) but creates an error during IntelliJ project builds:

```
Error:java: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/auto/service/AutoService
com.google.auto.service.AutoService
```

Noteworthy: The correct sources are generated into `generated-sources/annotations/...` but the IntelliJ build fails after this step and does not create the generated test sources directory `generated-test-sources/...`.

While the issue can be easily fixed by adding another annotation processor path to the `maven-compiler-plugin`

```
<path>
    <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-rc6</version>
</path>
```

this fix has the downside of looking up and manually changing the `auto-service` version whenever the `auto-value`-dependency version changes. Is there an obvious mistake i made in my pom file or a setting in IntelliJ i don't know? As far as i can see a correct annotation processing profile is created when i import the project into IntelliJ.

Comment: Is there a project you can share to check? See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212384#focus=streamItem-27-3484036.0-0 about what might be causing this.

Comment: I have the same problem but it builds correctly and the tests run but when I try to run outside of the test framework with Intellij I get the error you report.

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same issue, and I fixed it without touching to the code. Here's what I did:

1. In the **Settings/Preferences** dialog <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, go to **Build, Execution, Deployment** | **Compiler** | **Annotation Processors**.
2. Select the default, or select your own application profile or create a new one (click "+" on the bottom of the page).
3. Make sure **Enable annotation processing** is selected
4. Change the radio button from <s>**Processor path**</s> to **Obtain processors from the project classpath**.

Comment: ***** (5 Star) for " . . . without touching the code"

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a bug in IntelliJ, if it builds with `mvn` but not from within IntelliJ. I see the same thing. There is an alternative way of configuring AutoValue which avoids the problem:

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
      <artifactId>auto-value-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
      <artifactId>auto-value</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

You don't need the `<annotationProcessorPaths>` stuff in this case. On the downside, there's apparently some risk of the AutoValue annotation processor (the `auto-value` artifact) or its dependencies finding their way into your built project.

Comment: Thanks! After trying all sorts of recommendations like 1.configuring project source to include generated and 2.configuring `Annotation Processors`, your solution helped me solve my issue!